# conditional probability : planning and development questions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm not very sure about the resolution of this problem
Can you clarify this problem for me?

"In a course of 21 students, they must necessarily opt for a language workshop that can be English, French or both. It is known that the probability that he is enrolled in French knowing that he is in the English workshop is 1/5 and the probability that he is in the English workshop given that he is in the French one is 1/3. How many students are enrolled in both workshops?"

this is what i wear

If I = English and F = French
$$P(F\mid I)=1/5$$
$$P(I\mid F)=1/3$$
$$P(I \cup F) =1$$

I think they ask us

$$P(I \cap F)=?$$

If that's how I interpret it, I get to

$$P(I \cap F)=1/7$$

but I'm not sure, can you give me a more detailed explanation

Comment: Your answer $1/7$ seems correct to me (although you need to convert this probability into a count of number of students).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probability of $P(E \cap F) = \dfrac 17$ is correct.

If $e$ students opt for English language workshop, $f$ students opt for French and $g$ students for both,

$e + f - g = 21 \tag1$

Now using conditional probability we know that,

$ \displaystyle \frac{g}{e} = \frac 15 \implies \displaystyle e = 5g$

Similarly, $ \displaystyle \frac{g}{f} = \frac 13 \implies f = 3g$

Plugging into $(1)$, $ \displaystyle 5g + 3g - g  = 21$

$ \implies g = 3. ~$ So there are $3$ students who have opted for both English and French language workshops.

Comment: ,thanks for the indications, I understood perfectly